# Aligning Astronomical Images

Tags: python, iraf

I have few .fits files(images) of astronomical sources in different filters(U,B,V,R,I) taken at different nights. Now I have done astrometry on those images and have the wcs information.How to align those images so that I can add multiple images in each filter and increase the Signal to noise ratio. It should take into consideration both translation and rotation. Some python packages or codes or any task available with IRAF will be better.

I have tried geomap and geotran task available in IRAF.